# When extending the RepresentationModel<T> class of HATEOAS in the model using mongodb the application no longer works - spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-hateoas, java-17, mongock

I'm studying spring building an API using spring-boot,mongodb,lombok, mongock... this
[project](https://github.com/eduardosilva218/pokeapi).

When putting HATEOAS I had problems, I noticed that it was related the moment I inherit the `RepresentationModel<T> class`.

[Error complete](https://pastebin.com/zeLf1rhT)

Looks like the error is here:
`[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected`

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look to the error trace, it seems your repository is not properly injected into the Spring Context. Try adding the following to your Main class:

```java
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = ClientRepository.class)
```

Your main class should look like this(notice you can specify the package, instead listing the repository classes):

```java
@EnableMongock
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = {IItemRepository.class, ITrainerRepository.class})
public class PokeApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PokeApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem continued, the repository works fine. The problem only happens when I inherit this RepresentationModel<T> in my models.
If  remove inherit RepresentationModel<T> of models the api it works normally.

Comment: I even know how to solve it, I would create a model to use with HATEOAS and another to use with mongo and to create an adapter between them. It works, but it would be a technical debt from the start.

Comment: I highly recommend separating your representation model(HATEOAS) from your persistence. The work to map one to another is worthy...regardless the issue you are experimenting now.